# Setting OG tags in Facebook Canvas App

Tags: facebook, canvas

I'm trying to set different Open Graph tags for different pieces of content in my canvas. For example, http://apps.facebook.com/someapp/?pic_id=1 should be linted differently than .../?pic_id=2. Any suggestions how to do this, because Facebook doesn't seem to read the OG tags at all. URL: http://apps.facebook.com/city_theme_dev

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply generatoe the correct og_tag based on the query string parameter will do